# Deploy to a node-pool with a minimum node size of 0?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a node pool with a minimum pool size of 0, and a max pool size of 3. Normally, nothing is happening on this node pool, so GKE correctly scales down to zero. However, if I tried to submit a job to this pool via `kubectl`, the pod fails with Unschedulable.

I can run a `kubectl` with `--enable-autoscaling --min-nodes 1 --max-nodes 3` wait 10 seconds, and then deploy, and then wait for completion before changing the min-nodes back to 0 but this doesn't seem ideal.

Is there a better way to get the pool to start a node when a pod is pending?

Comment: Why are you scaling your cluster to 0? Is it for tests?

Comment: to save money. i use it to run batch jobs, it’s often sitting idle otherwise

Answer (score 1):

Even with something like taints or nodeAffinity, I don't think you can tell Kubernetes to spin up nodes in order to schedule workloads. The scheduler requires a node to be available already.

(Out of curiosity, how were you scheduling jobs to a specific nodepool via `kubectl`?)

Comment: with a node selector in the yaml file, and using kubectl apply -f.

Answer (score 1):

As the autoscaler is based on Pod resource requests to scale up/down, you need at least 1 value that autoscaler can use as base calculation to know if the pool need additional node or not.

Here is more information about How cluster autoscaler works [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler#how_cluster_autoscaler_works)